# Use Corona renderer for rendering models in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We are trying to use forge to render 360 view images for furniture models. Unfortunately, we need to use corona plugin for it. But while attaching dll files like we see in documentation - we still see an issue.

> [08/17/2021 15:07:15] 8/17/2021 15:07:15 PM;  DLL <t:\aces\applications\7b3e91f490aad59bb1502fc04a07ae97.ngrdh8rpmufavx5peithdvrycazwjxfq.renderall_1629212808[1].package\renderingtools.bundle\content\2021\CoronaMax2021.dlr> failed to initialize properly - not loading.
> [08/17/2021 15:07:15] 8/17/2021 15:07:15 PM;  DLL <t:\aces\applications\7b3e91f490aad59bb1502fc04a07ae97.ngrdh8rpmufavx5peithdvrycazwjxfq.renderall_1629212808[1].package\renderingtools.bundle\content\2021\CoronaMaxUtils2021.dlt> failed to initialize properly - not loading.
> [08/17/2021 15:07:30] 8/17/2021 15:07:30 PM;  Initializing Python version: 3.7.6
> [08/17/2021 15:07:30] 8/17/2021 15:07:30 PM;  ***WARNING*** Missing dll: coronamaxutils2021.dlt - CoronaMtl
> [08/17/2021 15:07:30] 8/17/2021 15:07:30 PM;  ***WARNING*** Missing dll: coronamaxutils2021.dlt - CoronaLayeredMtl
> [08/17/2021 15:07:31] 8/17/2021 15:07:31 PM;  ***WARNING*** Missing dll: coronamaxutils2021.dlt - CoronaColor
> [08/17/2021 15:07:31] 8/17/2021 15:07:31 PM;  ***WARNING*** Missing dll: coronamax2021.dlr - CoronaRenderer
> [08/17/2021 15:07:32] 8/17/2021 15:07:32 PM;  MAXScript ExecuteMAXScriptScript Exception: -- Runtime error: Unable to open renderer, possible recursion; Error occurred in anonymous codeblock; filename: t:\aces\applications\7b3e91f490aad59bb1502fc04a07ae97.ngrdh8rpmufavx5peithdvrycazwjxfq.renderall_1629212808[1].package\renderingtools.bundle\content\RenderingTools.ms; position: 442; line: 15

And nothing renders, obviously. I include plugin files as described in the docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationPackage SchemaVersion="1.0" AutodeskProduct="3ds Max" ProductType="Application" ProductCode="3ds Max Rendering Tools Plugin" UpgradeCode="My UpgradeCode">
    <CompanyDetails />
    <Components Description="post-start-up scripts parts">
        <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="3ds Max" SeriesMin="2020" SeriesMax="2023" />
        <ComponentEntry AppName="RenderingTools" Version="1.0.0" ModuleName="./Content/RenderingTools.ms" />
    </Components>
    <Components Description="plugins parts">
        <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="3ds Max" SeriesMin="2020" SeriesMax="2021" />
        <ComponentEntry AppName="CoronaRenderer" ModuleName="./Content/2021/CoronaMax2021.dlr" />
        <ComponentEntry AppName="CoronaUtils" ModuleName="./Content/2021/CoronaMaxUtils2021.dlt" />
    </Components>
    <Components Description="light icon paths parts">
        <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="3ds Max" SeriesMin="2020" SeriesMax="2021" />
        <ComponentEntry ModuleName="./Content/2021/UI/Icons/" />
    </Components>
    <Components Description="dark icon paths parts">
        <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="3ds Max" SeriesMin="2020" SeriesMax="2021" />
        <ComponentEntry ModuleName="./Content/2021/UI/IconsDark/" />
    </Components>

</ApplicationPackage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design Automation will not load interface plugins, i.e. anything with icons, forms, user interactions.

From the output, the `CoronaMax2021.dlr` is failing to load.

Answer (score 1):

First, Corona is a third party render and from a licnesing perspective, you might want to double-check this is acceptable use case. Especially if they use some sort of "online" licensing, as the Design Automation environment will not allow the module to check for licensing via the internet. As long as it can be automated (without any UI interactions required) and licensing is not an issue, it could work.

Next, I would suggest to first try getting it working with a built-in 3ds Max renderer just for the steps (perhaps ART or Arnold). Do not worry about materials, etc, but get your script working without corona to be sure you have the automation worked out.

Then, you could try to work out the Corona issues (and no guarantees it can work because again it is a third party tool.) It might be obvious, but to be sure... From the ApplicationPackage it appears to be setup like an app store bundle. For 3ds Max Design Automation, you would need to also be sending all the necessary modules, and make sure the path is setup correctly to find them in your app bundle zip. An example for that is here: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/engines/max (see the PackageContents section). Note that similarly the app bundle is setup to load from a "contents" folder, but the modules must also be provided in the app bundle zip in the correct location. Another example is provided here: https://github.com/kevinvandecar/design.automation.3dsmax-csharp-meshoptimizer (use the deploy01 branch). You can find this example's bundle here: https://github.com/kevinvandecar/design.automation.3dsmax-csharp-meshoptimizer/tree/deploy01/forgesample/wwwroot/bundles. Note that the zip contains the folder structure and all the needed modules for the plugin.